# Angular 2 Form builder Group with default value from observable

Tags: angular, formbuilder

i'm trying to set FormBuilder default value form an Observable that i'm getting from server, here is my formBuilder :

```
 this.form = fb.group({
            label: this.label,
            actionType: [],
            description: [],
            HTTPMethod: [], 
            resourcePattern: [this.rP],
            status: [], 
            parameters: this.parameters ,

            linkedProcess: fb.group({
            Process: fb.group({
                label: []
            })
           }),

          associatedTasks: this.associatedTasks

        });
```

on ngOnit i'm getting data from server, and i'm trying to set my controls value like this :

```
   this.form.controls.label.updateValue(this.actionsG.Action.label);
```

it work for label because it's a simple control, but when i'm trying to do it for a ControlGroup like **linkedprocess** it doesn't work ! here is what i'm trying to do :

```
this.form.controls.linkedProcess.updateValue(this.actionsG.Action.linkedProcess.Process.label);
```

Comment: which Angular 2 RC are you using? (you can find this out by looking at your @angular modules in package.json > dependencies) Ex: "@angular/common": "2.0.0-rc.4"

Comment: i'm actually at beta 7

Comment: could you post your `actionsG` from the component and the children that are referenced? `Action.linkedProcess.Process.label` etc

Comment: sorry i didn't get what you're trying to say for me !, when i'm logging the actionG.Action.linkedProcess.Process.label i have the exact value "A9129"

Comment: no problem :) could you show the code where `actionG.Action.linkedProcess.Process.label` gets set to 'A9129'?

Comment: even with a simple value like : this.form.controls.linkedProcess.updateValue("simpleValue"); it does not work, it's like he cannot find the control label inside the control group :)